# Extracting PNG images from AVI movie

Tags: performance-tuning, export, import, image, video

I have written the following code to extract all images from an uncompressed AVI movie and to save them as sequential PNGs.

```
outputPath = "F:\\images\\";

nImages = Length@Import["F:\\movie.avi", "Frames"];

ParallelTable[

  image = Import["F:\\movie.avi", {"Frames", i}];
  strCounter = ToString@PaddedForm[i, 4, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}];
  Export[StringJoin[outputPath, "image_", strCounter, ".png"], image, "png"],

  {i, 1, nImages}
 ];
```

Can that be done faster?

Answer (score 6):

You could speed things up by opening the file once for import since you are saving all of the frames.

```
MapIndexed[
 Function[{value, index},
  Export[StringJoin[outputPath, "image_", 
    PaddedForm[First@index, 4, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}], ".png"], 
   value, "png"]],
 Import["F:\\movie.avi", "ImageList"]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You forgot ToString@PaddedForm ... My AVI contains 10.6 GB (2726 PNGs), each PNG is 4MPixel. AbsoluteTiming gives for your code 1736.97 sec and for my code 589.802 sec. . (I have a 4 core i7.) So your code is 3 times  slower.